# How to disable orientation change in AIR SDK for Android using Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, air

I am developing an AIR application (no flex, pure as3) for Android in Intellij IDEA, but I cannot find a way to disable orientation change. I remember when I was using flex builder, I could just tick a checkbox somewhere in the preferences and it updated the descriptor XML file with some lines. I cannot find the necessary lines and the actual XML file though.

How can be the orientation locked in portrait?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me.

It is a little bit cryptic, but here's how you do it:

1. Go to `File > Project Structure` (`cmd`+`;` on Mac)
2. Select `Modules` on the left pane
3. Choose your project (It will say something like "Project name (app)"
4. Select `Android` or `iOS` tab, depending on what you want to create a descriptor file for
5. Select `Custom template`
6. Press `Create` button
7. Select all your needed options, press `Create` and that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Open "YourAppname-app.xml" in the default src folder.
Search for "autoOrients" and set it's value to "false".
Then go for "aspectRatio" and set it to "portrait".

Some of the values might be commented out, so you might need to remove the comment around it first.

Comment: There is no such XML file :(

Comment: Oh, i've found such a descriptor file on the "out" directory, though for some reason it is not displayed in the project pane... I've found it only using finder. Is there any way I can reveal it in the project pane?

Comment: Don't know about IntelliJ, maybe it filters out xml files as it is using some for it's own configs. Anyway, if the trick worked, I'd highly appreciate you to mark the answer as correct ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work – the file gets replaced with a default one after the build is run :(

Comment: OK, so you are editing the file at the wrong location. Look for a file of the same name in your source folder. Maybe try a search. It HAS to be around somewhere. Sorry I cant tell you exactly where, but I'm using Flash Builder.

Comment: Well, i thought so, too, but there is None. Though, I've found that there is an option to use a custom template for this XML file instead of using the default one. It's something, but I cannot really understand that they mean by a "template" - it's seems it's not a regular XML-file, but some kind of template for it with context variables or so.

Comment: I've figured it out finally. Thank you for your helpe, I've upvoted your answer.